# Build queries dynamically to reduce the number of them

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I explain the problem:

I have a database structure as follows:

Sound 0 to many Version

Sound many to many Artists

Version many to many Instruments

Sound can have more Version but also can not have any.

When I build the view, I call through a cycle that also Version consequently also called Instruments, to have many queries to get a list.

If I have 20 lines of Sound I get more than 50 queries!

This invalidates a lot about performance, and I would like to know if there is a way to minimize these queries.

For now I run a join Sound - Artists and I reduced slightly queries executed, but I can not do a join also because otherwise Version exclude all rows that do not have Sound Version ..

Is there a way to reduce queries to a minimum?

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: You're right!
with a left join I solved the problem! Now only 2 queries!